# Bold a row in excel based on column value

Tags: excel, text, format, conditional-statements

Here's my problem:  I want to bold entire rows of my spreadsheet IF the value of one of the columns equals either 'Saturday' or 'Sunday'.  I've found ways to bold the cells, but not the entire row.  Can someone please help?
Oh, I would also like to increase the font, from 10 to 12, based on same condition.
Thanks!

Comment: `Selection.Font.Bold = True` and `Selection.Font.Size = 12` will help you then. Since you havent pasted your code I dont know where you will put it though, if you paste your code I can help more

Comment: Is the value actually something someone typed in as *Saturday* or is it a date that has been formatted *dddd*?

Comment: It is something typed in, not a date formatted dddd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ... I got a bit bored and made this for you

```
Sub Test()

Dim cRow as Long
Dim rRow As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

'Gets the last row with data in it
LastRow = [A65000].End(xlUp).Row

'the look to move down the cells
For cRow = 1 To LastRow

'if statment so catch the values that are wanted
If Cells(cRow, 1) = "Saturday" Or Cells(cRow, 1) = "Sunday" Then

'the changes made to the rows
Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
Rows(cRow).Font.Size = 12

End If

Next cRow


End Sub
```

Brief explincation, the `LastRow` gets the last row in column A (this is needed so we dont go past any of the data we need and intoblank cells (Change the column letter to which ever column you need))

The loop `For cRow = 1 To LastRow` (the cRow will +1 for each `Next cRow`) will count down the cells till it reachs the `LastRow`

The `If Cells(cRow, 1) = "Saturday" Or Cells(cRow, 1) = "Sunday" Then` will check the cell and if it has the value in the cell it will then change it to bold and size 12 font

If there is anything you are unclear of in the code let me know and I will try to clarify

Comment: Mr.Burns, thanks, that did exactly what I needed it to

Comment: No problem, accept this as anwser by clicking the tick on the left of answers to show the question has been answered

Answer (score 0):

```
Private TurnRowToBold()
lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lLastRow
    If (Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(i, 1) = "Saturday" or Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(i, 1) = "Sunday") Then
        Worksheets("MySheet").Rows(i).Font.Bold = True
        Worksheets("MySheet").Rows(i).Font.Size = 12
    End If
Next
End Sub
```